# Using sql.js in an Electron application

Tags: javascript, sqlite, electron

I am new to [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/). It's pure awesome, and getting started is super fun and easy. For some time now I have been trying to find a "database" solution to use in my application. Of course there is the Web SQL/local storage options, but I am trying to use SQLite. I found [sql.js](https://github.com/kripken/sql.js), which is great and easy to use. I could get everything to run correctly put I cannot save/update the database file! 
Here is the code:

```
    var remote = require('remote'),
    fileSystem = remote.require('fs'),
    sql = remote.require('./nodeModules/sql.js'),
    database = new sql.Database(fileSystem.readFileSync('./database.sqlite'));

    database.run('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (ID integer primary key autoincrement, name text, price integer, stock integer)');

    // Save the data back to the file
    var data = database.export();
    var buffer = new Buffer(data);
    fileSystem.writeFileSync("./database.sqlite", buffer);
```

But I am getting this error from "Buffer": `Uncaught TypeError: must start with number, buffer, array or string`. Have you run across this issue before ?

Comment: Did you get this working by chance? I'm thinking about using sql.js for something in electron myself.

Comment: Sadly no. I've tried, but failed

Comment: I got it to work on OS X.  I have not tried Windows yet.  https://github.com/codewisdom/electron-sqljs

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to reproduce this issue on node v6.2.2 (npm v3.9.4) on Windows 10 and OS X 10.11.5.  The code is nearly identical to yours:

```
fs.writeFileSync("filename.sqlite", new Buffer(db.export()));
```

Check out this repo for more information:
https://github.com/codewisdom/electron-sqljs

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to read and write the database to the folder returned by calling:

```js
electron.app.getPath('userData')
```

I created an [example project showing how to use sql.js in Electron](https://github.com/patrickmoffitt/local-sqlite-example/blob/master/README.md).